# How can I use data in df.x and use functions to select and add to df.y

Tags: r

I am new to R and I am trying to write a piece of code that will enable me to pick some data in df.x and put it in df.y:

```
Category 2019 2020 2021 2022 2023
Apple      3    4    5    6    7
Pear       3    4    5    6    7
Banana     3    4    5    6    7
Oranges    3    4    5    6    7
```

I want to select the value for oranges in 2019 and put in df.y and differences in years for Apple into a new df.y, like this:

```
Resource 2019 2020 2021 2022 2023
Orange     3    4    5    6    7
Apple           1    1    1    1
```

Any helps are appreciated!!!
Thanks

Comment: can you clarify the logic and your desired output, not sure if your written description matches what you want in `df.y`

Comment: Hi EJJ, basically I want to use df.x data to either pick the value and put in df.y or I want to do some calculation using df.x i.e. for example 2020.Apple value minus 2019 Apple value and put it into df.y....

Answer (score 0):

This is a `tidyverse` approach involving wide to long transform since it's easier to calculate the year differences.

```
library(tidyverse)

df.x <- tibble(
  Category = c("Apple", "Pear", "Banana", "Orange"),
  "2019" = 3,
  "2020" = 4,
  "2021" = 5,
  "2022" = 6,
  "2023" = 7
)

df.y <- df %>% 
  filter(Category %in% c("Apple", "Orange")) %>% 
  pivot_longer(-Category) %>% 
  mutate(value = ifelse(Category == "Apple", value - lag(value, 1), value)) %>% 
  pivot_wider()

# A tibble: 2 x 6
#  Category `2019` `2020` `2021` `2022` `2023`
#  <chr>     <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
#1 Apple        NA      1      1      1      1
#2 Orange        3      4      5      6      7
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to provide your data using `dput(df.x)`:

```
df.x <- structure(list(Category = c("Apple", "Pear", "Banana", "Oranges"
), X2019 = c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), X2020 = c(4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), X2021 = c(5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L), X2022 = c(6L, 6L, 6L, 6L), X2023 = c(7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Note that your column names have changed because R does not allow column/variable names to begin with a number. The process for extracting information from a data frame is covered in detail on the manual page: `?Extract`. It is a bit dense so it may be easier to begin with some introductory tutorials on R.

To extract the row for `Oranges`:

```
row1 <- df.x[df.x$Category=="Oranges", ]
row1
#   Category X2019 X2020 X2021 X2022 X2023
# 4  Oranges     3     4     5     6     7
```

The row number indicates that this is the 4th row in df.x. Now the second row is slightly more involved. First extract the row:

```
row2 <- df.x[df.x$Category=="Apple", ]
row2
#   Category X2019 X2020 X2021 X2022 X2023
# 1    Apple    NA     1     1     1     1
```

Now compute the differences across the row by converting the data frame row to a simple vector with `unlist` since `diff` is picky about what kind of data structure it will work with and insert a missing value, `NA`, for the first year:

```
row2[ , -1] <- c(X2019=NA, diff(unlist(row2[, -1])))
df.y <- rbind(row1, row2)
df.y
#   Category X2019 X2020 X2021 X2022 X2023
# 4  Oranges     3     4     5     6     7
# 1    Apple    NA     1     1     1     1
rownames(df.y) <- NULL
```

The last line just resets the row names which have carried over from `df.x`.